# Unit conversion of DEM

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, dem, file-geodatabase, arcswat

I have a 10-m resolution DEM, in the form of a .gdb. The "Value" field is in feet and cannot be edited. I am working with SWAT -- which uses the Band 1/Value field-- and assumes units are in meters. I have tried copying the raster and creating a new attribute table. Creating an additional field and converting from ft to meters will not work in this case as I have no way of selecting it as the elevation band. Any suggestions for creating a new DEM in which the units are in meters?

Comment: Thanks, that is all it took!

Answer (score 2):

If you have a Spatial or 3D Analyst extension license for ArcGIS, you can create a metres raster by dividing the feet raster by 3.281 using the [Raster Calculator](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/raster-calculator.htm).

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by user2856, you can use Raster Calculator. Raster Calculator creates a new raster with new values.

If you do not have a Spatial or 3D Analyst license for ArcGIS, you can use Raster Calculator in QGIS for this spesific job, and then import your new raster back to ArcGIS.
https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_raster/raster_analysis.html#raster-calculator
The documententation linked above includes an example of converting a raster from meters to feet, so you need to do it the reverse way.